# Can I make a skeleton from a zombie?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, necromancy

If I were to raise an undead zombie but I wanted a skeleton instead could I burn or peel off the flesh of the zombie in order to obtain a skeleton? If I did that would the zombie's stats change to a skeleton's or remain a zombie's?

Comment: can I ask the obvious question: since *Animate Undead* can create either zombies or skeletons, why not just butcher the corpses first *then* animate the resulting skeletons? Or are you hoping to get at something that looks like a skeleton but has zombie stats? Or are you just in a glut of zombies and would like to convert some?

Comment: [The fastest way to remove bones from a man](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93646/the-fastest-way-to-remove-bones-from-a-man) - My favorite question on here, and it's relevant!

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to animate undead creatures beyond existing spells' restrictions, such as size?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93881/33569), [Can the Animate Dead spell be cast on a zombie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74143/33569), [Can the Animate Dead spell be cast on any dead creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55960/33569), [Can a Necromancer reuse the corpses left behind from slain undead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143832/33569)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, but you'll have to kill it and strip the flesh off first. Not necessarily in that order. Peeling the flesh off of a zombie would cause it to fall apart and die.**

Animate Dead (PHB p.212) describes that you need to cast the spell on "a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small creature". If you pick the former you'll get a skeleton. Zombies have bones, but given how the rules phrase it you'll need to have a pile of bones to make a skeleton rather than pulling them out of a creature. So to turn a zombie into a skeleton you'll need to kill it, strip its flesh off, pile the bones, then cast Animate Dead on it. Voila, you now have a skeleton instead of a zombie!

Comment: Does a zombie really need bones to be "alive"?

Comment: @PremierBromanov As I understand this answer, it is just that any process involving separating zombie from bones would necessarily result in lethal damage.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, that's what I meant. Also, I know that in at least one earlier edition (3.5) there is a monster that is specifically the animated flesh that stays behind when animating a skeleton.

Comment: The issue of whether *animate dead* can be cast on the corpses of undead creatures is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15): "**Can I cast *animate dead* on the humanoid-shaped corpse of an undead creature such as a zombie or a ghast?** No. *Animate dead* targets only the corpses of creatures that have the humanoid creature type." You may want to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So long as each damaging event resulted in 18 points of damage or fewer, good rolls on _Undead Fortitude_ could keep the zombie alive even after removing all of its bones.  It certainly would be _easier_ to kill it first, as this answer suggests, but I don't think it would be _required_.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you cannot, as Animate Dead ruling (PHB p.212) stipulates that you need to "Choose a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small **humanoid** within range". Using the stat block, as proposed by [Jeremy Crawford's tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/696759839838449664) (see below), the animated corpse becomes a zombie, a **undead** type creature. It ceases to be a **humanoid** and won't ever be a legal for the animate dead spell again.

I believe the answer above is incorrect.

---

The tweet:

> Q: When animate dead is cast on a corpse/skeleton, do you use the Monster manual statistics, or add a template? — [@Johnathan_Lin on Feb 8, 2016](https://twitter.com/Johnathan_Lin/status/696756183323947010)
>
> A: When you cast animate dead, use the skeleton/zombie stat block from the Monster Manual or appendix D in the PH. — [@JeremyECrawford on Feb 8, 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/696759839838449664)

Comment: To improve this answer, I think you should flesh (no pun intended) out the details of the change of creature type. Does a corpse of a humanoid that has been raised as a zombie, then killed again change it back to the corpse of a humanoid, or is it a corpse of an undead?

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.se. Please take our [tour] when you have time. Great catch on the wording being "of a humanoid" rather than "of a creature". As Thomas mentioned, the answer could be improved by backing it up on how a creature that has been animated into a zombie stops being a humanoid. IIRC there is a Crawford tweet about it, but you also could find stuff about that in other questions about revivifying creatures.

Comment: Thank you for your great comment. I initially assumed that the zombie created was from drawn from the stat block. Luckily enough my hunch could be verified.

Comment: Given you're asserting the other answer is incorrect, you may want to address the "pile of bones" thing, which is what it's proposing as a way to raise a skeleton. (Note that the other answer never claims you can directly animate the zombie corpse itself.)

Comment: @doppelgreener I believe the proposed interpretation is "a pile of bones of a Medium or Small humanoid".

Comment: Very relevant Q&As: [Can a Necromancer reuse the corpses left behind from slain undead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143832/33569), [Can the Animate Dead spell be cast on a zombie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74143/33569)

Comment: Also, the issue of whether *animate dead* can be cast on the corpses of undead creatures is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15): "**Can I cast *animate dead* on the humanoid-shaped corpse of an undead creature such as a zombie or a ghast?** No. *Animate dead* targets only the corpses of creatures that have the humanoid creature type." You may want to update your answer accordingly.