# Is it possible to get a permanent skeleton companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, necromancy

This is a follow up question to [Can I make a skeleton from a zombie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80349/can-i-make-a-skeleton-from-a-zombie)

In D&D 5e, there are very few ways to get a permanent necrotic follower. Usually you have to reassert control over them. [*Finger of death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death), I think, is the only way to get a permanent undead follower, but I am pretty sure that only applies to zombies, as cited below.

> A humanoid killed by this spell rises at the start of your next turn as a **zombie** that is **permanently** under your command

I am interested in the exhaustion immunity of skeletons, and enjoy their appearance much more than the zombies.

**Is it possible to get a permanent skeleton companion?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes, it is possible

It is actually possible to obtain a permanent skeleton companion. That being said, it is a slightly convoluted process that is not without certain shortcomings. This method involves using two spells in conjunction:

***Finger of Death***

> A humanoid killed by this spell rises at the start of your next turn as a **zombie** that is **permanently under your command,** following your verbal orders to the best of its ability.

***True Polymorph***

> Choose one creature or nonmagical object that you can see within range. You transform that creature into a different creature ... **If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation becomes permanent.** ... If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be any kind you choose whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's. The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form. **It retains its alignment and personality**. ...

By now, you probably understand where I'm going with this. You would first start by using *Finger of Death* to create a normal zombie servant under your control. Next, you would use the *True Polymorph* spell to transform said zombie into a skeleton (which you can do because they are both challenge rating 1/4). Then you simply wait out the spell's duration, which makes the transformation permanent, and, since a transformed creature "retains its alignment and personality" you now have one permanent skeleton companion at your disposal.

In fact, using this method, you could create a permanent companion out of any creature of 1/4 challenge rating you may desire.

In Summary

*Finger of Death* + *True Polymorph* = permanent skeleton companion

Comment: The ecology of zombies and skeletons in d&d is that removing the flesh from a zombie makes it a skeleton.   No true polymorph required.

Answer (score -11):

I'm pretty sure you can make a permanent animated dead, including a skeleton, using the awaken spell as a bard or druid. [image]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. Please take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). Can you please elaborate on how do you intend to raise a skeleton with this spell? From what I see, it can only awake a (living) beast or plant. It is also not under your control, which is something the asker wants, it is only charmed (check the charmed condition). Finally, even the charm is not permanent - so it is not actually a guaranteed way to get a permanent companion. It could easily become hostile to you, or simply stay friendly but not accompany you.

Comment: may i ask what makes a skeleton a "beast or plant"? this seems like a major issue in your answer and i am down-voting until you can explain better.