# Can a necromancer True Polymorph to get an arbitrary CR 9-or-less companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, polymorph, necromancy

According to [If you True Polymorph a zombie you create via Finger of Death, does it remain under your command?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117236/41793) after a necromancer polymorphs an undead they control, it is still under their control. Assuming yes, I raise you an even more overpowered combo than a bunch of pixies running around:

1. A necromancer gets a permanent zombie via Finger of Death.
2. The zombie gets polymorphed into an object via True Polymorph.
3. After taking a long rest, the necromancer uses True Polymorph again, this time going for the "Object into Creature" option, turning their permanent zombie into any creature with a CR of 9 or less.

Is this possible RAW?

Comment: The title should summarise and indicate the content of the question, not be a whole different question all on its own -- I've moved that titular question into the question body, and modified the title to indicate this is a question about whether a particular combo works.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. Neither linked question addresses the object-creature link

Comment: I've reopened it as this appears to be a substantially different question than merely getting a skeleton and from the method described in the skeleton question (as @lucasvw points out).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### No, for multiple reasons.

The [original answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80438/32262) you're referring to depends on this particular phrase in the "creature to creature" portion of the spell text:

> The target's game Statistics, including mental Ability Scores, are replaced by the Statistics of the new form. It retains its alignment and personality.

However, you're using the "creature to object" and "object to creature" portions of the spell. The "creature to object" portion of the spell doesn't say that alignment and personality are retained:

> The creature's Statistics become those of the object, and the creature has no memory of time spent in this form, after the spell ends and it returns to its normal form.

Therefore, the basis of that answer does not apply to your question.

Furthermore, the object to creature portion *explicitly states* that you lose control of the creature when the spell becomes permanent:

> If the spell becomes permanent, you no longer control the creature. It might remain friendly to you, depending on how you have treated it.

This passage means that even if you did have permanent control over the polymorphed zombie, it is no longer under your control once you make True Polymorph permanent.

Comment: I think the "If the spell becomes permanent, you no longer control the creature." part of True Polymorph only refers to the control granted by True Polymorph itself, not all types of control over the creature. Also, since the creature doesn't remember the time spent in this form, it could be concluded that being in object form has no affect on a creature's personality or alignment.

Comment: @KombatKingo If there were such a stipulation, it would be written into the spell text. "You no longer control the creature" seems pretty clear-cut to me.

Comment: @KombatKingo you did ask for RAW. That is the answer Icyfire gave. He is right. There is no distinction between which type of control

Comment: @KombatKingo It is *probably intended* that the "no longer control the creature" refers to the control allowed by the True Polymorph, not other ways. But you have, yourself, asked for RAW. What is written is: you no longer control the creature. Period.