# Can a dispelled zombie's remains be reanimated?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, necromancy

How the *animate dead* spell works in the video game *Baldur's Gate 3* has me wondering:

Can I reanimate the remains of a dispelled zombie?

- Does it remain a zombie (undead creature) after dispelling, and remain exempt from *animate dead*
- Or is it again a humanoid corpse, and thus a valid target for the spell?

Some of the answers to similar questions address a destroyed or "killed" zombie, but not a dispelled zombie.

Comment: I added the 5e tag for you as the text of your question is asking about 5e

Comment: What do you mean by "dispelled zombie" in terms of 5e? And how do you want to reanimate it, using what feature/spell exactly?

Comment: It seems to me that BG3 questions ought to be fielded at [arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'll make a meta of how to treat those, as many of them are essentially questions about how the 5e rules work, triggered by someone playing the game.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Good idea. Not sure how this should be treated. 

Comment: Are you asking about how that stuff works in BG3, or about how it works in the paper & pencil RPG 5th edition D&D, which is what BG3 is based off (with some important differences)?

Comment: I’ve removed the question about reanimating bones, that’s an entirely different question, and we try to keep posts focused on one question per post. You are free to create a new question posts for additional questions.

Comment: I see it's been edited out, but in case there was something important in it. Why did this related to BG3 zombies. It rather distinctly doesn't include *dispel magic* so I'm failing to see the connection. (And it would seem I'm not alone in that.)

Comment: It being edited out really makes the answer seem odd

Comment: Related [Can you dispel animated dead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130561/can-you-dispel-animated-dead/130562#130562)

Comment: I'm voting to close for now, but would love to hear from @Bex what the focus of their question is really about. Is this a question about what you saw in BG3 and are asking if what you saw is accurate? Or do you have a  question about the game itself? Or is it something else? I just want to make sure we're answering the question you have and not the question we think you have.

Comment: Okay, the  forced edit of my ask really made it unintelligible. I am an old school tabletop DnD player who hasn't updated to 5e, on which BG3 is based. I was asking if in 5e, dispelling zombies is a thing, and if so, can the same corpse/ex zombie be reanimated again, or is a fresh corpse required. The mechanics in BG3 made me wonder - you can dispel but not reanimate the same corpse - and I thought allowing one but not the other was odd and got curious. My question was answered by the confirmation that dispelling zombies still isn't a thing in tabletop, so it's just a weird BG3 thing.

Answer (score 5):

### You cannot dispel Zombies in D&D 5e

[*Animate Dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead), the spell that creates zombies is a spell with an instantaneous duration. You cannot dispel effects of spells with an instantaneous duration.

This has been explicitly answered in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA180):

> **Can you use *dispel magic* on the creations of a spell like *animate dead* or affect those creations with antimagic field?**
>
> Whenever you wonder whether a spell’s effects can be dispelled or suspended, you need to answer one question: is the spell’s duration instantaneous? If the answer is yes, there is nothing to dispel or suspend. Here’s why: the effects of an instantaneous spell are brought into being by magic, but the effects aren’t sustained by magic (see *PH*, 203). The magic flares for a split second and then vanishes. For example, the instantaneous spell *animate dead* harnesses magical energy to turn a corpse or a pile of bones into an undead creature. That necromantic magic is present for an instant and is then gone. The resulting undead now exists without the magic’s help. Casting *dispel magic* on the creature can’t end its mockery of life, and the undead can wander into an antimagic field with no adverse effect. [...]

Of course there are many other ways to off zombies, from just beating them down, to a cleric of level 5 or higher using their [Channel Divinity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ChannelDivinity) to destroy them. (Thanks to [@KorvinStarmast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208237/animate-dead-in-bg3-has-me-wondering/208238?noredirect=1#comment571486_208238).)

Wether you can reuse the corpses of zombies that were destroyed in some way in 5e is covered by [Can a Necromancer reuse the corpses left behind from slain undead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143832/can-a-necromancer-reuse-the-corpses-left-behind-from-slain-undead?noredirect=1&lq=1) in detail. Short answer (also based on [the SAC](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA265)): yes, if the creature at some point was a humanoid.

> **Can I cast *animate dead* on the humanoid-shaped corpse of an undead creature such as a zombie or a ghast?**
>
> When *animate dead* targets a corpse, the body must have belonged to a creature of the humanoid creature type. If the spell targets a pile of bones, there is no creature type restriction; the bones become a skeleton.

Comment: But a level 5 or higher cleric can destroy them with channel divinity.
{Lvl  |   CR Undead Destroyed }  
{5th | 1/2 or lower } 
{8th |1 or lower  }
{11th | 2 or lower  }
{14th | 3 or lower  }
{ 17th | 4 or lower }